# Type difference on image processing on Openframeworks

Tags: opencv, openframeworks

Openframeworks, opencv, and third parties respectively provide different type of image (ofxCv, ofxOpenCv, ofImage, cv::Mat, IplImage ...etc).
I'm wondering if there is a detailed document on these differences.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ofImage](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofImage/) is the main image type in OpenFrameworks. Be sure to checkout [ofPixels()](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofPixels/) (used for ofImage pixel access) and [ofTexture](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/gl/ofTexture/)(used to render an ofImage on screen)

ofOpenCv is the first OpenCV addon for OpenFrameworks and it ships with it.
It has it's image format: [ofxCvImage](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/ofxOpenCv/ofxCvImage/) which is

> made to provide interoperability between the core OF imaging types,
>   ofImage and ofTexture, and OpenCv.

[IplImage](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=iplimage#IplImage) is a format/structure for OpenCV images, but the older C based API.
In OpenCV 2.x and 3.x favours an easier format to work with [cv::Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html?highlight=mat)

The catch is ofxOpenCv was developed quite a while back, when IplImage was more commonly used. If you're working with older OpenCV C api based code and you would like to integrate that into an OpenFrameworks project, use ofxOpenCv and ofxCvImage since they provide a bridge between OpenCV's IplImage and openFrameworks' image format.

If you're getting started with OpenCV and OpenFrameworks now, I recommend using the newer OpenCV API and cv::Mat which [ofxCv](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv) integrates very nicely.
When I use OpenCV in OpenFrameworks I use ofxCv and I tend to do most of the work in cv::Mat format. Only at the last stage, when I need to render the OpenCV image processing results in OpenFrameworks I make use [ofxCv's utilties](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv/blob/master/libs/ofxCv/include/ofxCv/Utilities.h)(see Utilities, Wrappers and Helpers) to convert back and forth between the formats. Most commonly I use:

- `toCv()` to convert from OpenFrameworks to `cv::Mat` format
- `toOf()` rarely to convert from `cv::Mat` to `ofImage`
- `drawMat()` often to render `cv::Mat` results straight into openFrameworks

Be sure to go through ofxCv examples. They are fun and there's a lot to learn from them. Have fun!

**Update** [ofBook's Varieties of oF Image Containers (Data Structures)](http://openframeworks.cc/ofBook/chapters/image_processing_computer_vision.html#Varieties%20of%20oF%20Image%20Containers%20(Data%20Structures)) section also provides detailed information on `ofImage`, `ofCvImage` and `cv::Mat`. Be sure to check it out!

[image: ofImage]

> To the greatest extent possible, the designers of openFrameworks (and addons for image processing, like ofxOpenCV and Kyle McDonald's [ofxCv](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv)) have provided simple operators to help make it easy to exchange data between these containers.